# I can't buy gems in Clash of Clans, conflicting Apple IDs

Tags: apple-id, game-center, in-app-purchase, clash-of-clans

I downloaded Clash of Clans using my sisters Apple ID and her Game Center, on my iPhone. I backed up my phone. Then when I got my new phone and I created a new Apple ID and new Game Center for me.

I had kept all my progress from my earlier phone. However, now when I try to buy gems, it pops up with this message:

> This item is for an app that has been purchased by a different Apple ID. To buy this item with this Apple ID you must first purchase the app.

I am guessing this means I have to delete the app and re-download it, but I am afraid I will lose all my progress.

Is there an easy solution for the Apple ID confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Supercell saves your progress under your Game Center account. So, if you get a new device with a new Game Center account, you will lose your progress. To keep your progress, you will need to link your device to hers in the Clash of Clans settings.

Comment: Can you confirm whether in-app-purchase for this game is tied to the AppleID used in the iOS App Store, the AppleID used in GameCenter or the AppleID used in iCloud Documents? I could see the programmers choosing any of the three for various reasons. Adding that detail would be a big help as the game is quite popular to many.

Comment: @bmike The in-app purchases are through iTunes, so they are through the App Store. Your progress in the game is on Game Center.

Comment: Of course they start there, but once the purchase is redeemed, where the gem balance actually get stored could be in several places. If you don't know, no worries - still worth a +1 without the additional detail.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite simple. The account you're signed into is **not** the account used to buy or download Clash of Clans.

Sign out with the current iTunes Store account under Store section in Preferences, and sign in with the one used to purchase CoC. Alternatively, you can delete the app and download it with the current account again. The progress is tied with your Game Center account, so your progress won't be lost.

All IAP in this game is one-time, so after purchasing, the effect is tied to your CoC progress and the current GameCenter account. If you ever need more for any GC/CoC account, you'll need to purchase again.

Comment: All of that is correct, except that the OP has changed their Game Center, meaning that they will have to start over.